# pm2 - Is there a way to restrict some code for master only?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I'm trying to use [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) to deploy my nodejs application.

I have some cron jobs that should get executed only once. With PM2 cluster mode, I'm able to scale my application across multiple CPUs, but all of them will execute my cron jobs.

Just like the nodejs API has `cluster.isMaster` or `cluster.isWorker`, is there a way I can ask only the PM2 master to execute it?

Comment: Posting as this will be helpful for an another person looking for this: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34446969/how-can-we-configure-master-process-when-using-pm2